# carry over other variables in summary

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=1:10,x=rnorm(10),group=rep(1:2,each=5), gc=rep(c(10,20), each=5))

> dat
    id           x group gc
 1:  1  1.37095845     1 10
 2:  2 -0.56469817     1 10
 3:  3  0.36312841     1 10
 4:  4  0.63286260     1 10
 5:  5  0.40426832     1 10
 6:  6 -0.10612452     2 20
 7:  7  1.51152200     2 20
 8:  8 -0.09465904     2 20
 9:  9  2.01842371     2 20
10: 10 -0.06271410     2 20
```

and I would like to summarize `x` per group.

```
> dat[,.(mx=mean(x)), by=group]
   group        mx
1:     1 0.4413039
2:     2 0.6532896
```

does this perfectly. However, I would also like to carry `gc` over, which is some group characteristic and therefore constant within group. I tried

```
> dat[,.(gc, mx=mean(x)), by=group]
    group gc        mx
 1:     1 10 0.4413039
 2:     1 10 0.4413039
 3:     1 10 0.4413039
 4:     1 10 0.4413039
 5:     1 10 0.4413039
 6:     2 20 0.6532896
 7:     2 20 0.6532896
 8:     2 20 0.6532896
 9:     2 20 0.6532896
10:     2 20 0.6532896
```

but this appears to create recycle `mx` for each original entry in `dat`. In SQL-manner, I thought

```
dat[,.(gc=max(gc), mx=mean(x)), by=group]
```

would do the trick, but it only produces an error. I wonder what other trick there is to get:

```
> res
   group gc        mx
1:     1 10 0.4413039
2:     2 20 0.6532896
```

I am sure this question must have occurred before, but I couldn't find the answer — quite possibly, because my meta-vocabulary for these types of operations is small and I used the wrong search terms.

Comment: Why not just include `gc` in the grouping which is a group characteristic anyways?

Comment: Like @Shree said, just do `dat[,.(mx=mean(x)), by=.(group, gc)]`

Comment: There is also the `first` function in `data.table` that pulls the first observation of a variable by group.

Comment: excellent advice, thanks. Anyone make it a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
dat[, .(gc = gc[1], mx = mean(x)), by = group]
```